# How to solve ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'samba_tools.XXX'

Tags: samba

When I try to compile my model, I see this module import error,

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'samba_tools.XXX'`

I have already tried to restart my docker and rebuild. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall samba_tools (pip uninstall samba_tools ). You might see that it's not installed.

Next, go to `sambaflow/samba_tools` and delete the egg file. (delete .local and .local_python )

Finally, do `pip install .`